# UISearchDisplayController doesn't reload data when searching only by scope

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, uisearchdisplaycontroller, searchbar

I have a UITableViewController that that use a simple SearchBar for filtering result. I'm using an array of candies with name and category and I'm using these categories as options for the scope bar of my SearchBar. 
I have an utility function to apply the filter:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    // Filter the array using the filter method
    self.filteredCandies = self.candies.filter(){( candy: Candy) -> Bool in
        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (candy.category == scope)
        let stringMatch = candy.name.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
    }
}
```

I call this function in the `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:` method and in the  `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:` method.

If I put some text in the SearchBar everything works, even when I choose a scope from the scope bar. The problem is that when I clear the text (or when I choose a scope without put any text) the filter doesn't applied. With some debugging I saw that the array is well filtered when the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called but the tableView simply show all the elements, not the filtered ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality of the `UISearchDisplayController` is to only display the `searchResultsTableView` when there is text in the search bar. The best way to work around this that I have found is to create your own segmented controller to use as a scope bar and filter the actual data source for your tableview by the scope and then filter that by search text when a search string is entered.

Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by reloading my tableview from the delegate method.

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    println("Scope Changed")
    updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController)
}
```

That last function should contain code for resetting your filter / remaking your array / fetching all objects from coredata (if that's what you're doing) AND reloading your tableView.